# Google Cloud Print "403 User credentials required"

Tags: php, guzzle, google-cloud-print

I have seen posts with the same problem that I am facing, however, I do not get it to work, even with the changes the other posts suggests.

So when I fail with other google API's I usually get an (informative) errorcode and or message. But not in this case.

Using PHP with Guzzle i try to do this request.

```
$headers = [
        RequestOptions::HEADERS => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $oResponse->access_token,
            'X-CloudPrint-Proxy' => 'Google-JS',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept-Charset' => 'utf-8',
        ]
    ];

    $getPrinters = $client
        ->post('https://www.google.com/cloudprint/search?output=json', $headers)
        ->getBody()
        ->getContents();
```

But I get this:

`` Client error: `POST https://www.google.com/cloudprint/search?output=json` resulted in a `403 User credentials required` response: <HTML> <HEAD> <TITLE>User credentials required</TITLE> </HEAD> <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"> <H1>User credenti (truncated...) ``

I've tried with different kinds of headers, but they all return the same result.

`$oResponse->access_token` comes from this part (Which works)

```
    $response = $client->post('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token', [
        RequestOptions::FORM_PARAMS => [
            'refresh_token' => 'valid token',
            'client_id' => 'xxxxx',
            'client_secret' => 'xxxxx',
            'grant_type' => 'refresh_token'
        ],
        RequestOptions::HEADERS => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ]
    ])->getBody()->getContents();

    $oResponse = json_decode($response);
```

Also I didn't find anything useful on the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/appInterfaces) either. But again, maybe I just misinterpreted it.

I have also tried other clients for HTTP requests, like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and in "raw curl". But still the same result.

So. What can I do next?

Cheers

Comment: I think it's asking for your username and password. `user@domain.com:password` style credentials. Try using the email address and password you use to login to the console.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/sendJobs and [Authentication](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/pythonCode#authentication) Its has Python example but it gives an example where how and what credentials to use.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the access token is obtained via OAuth.

Also change https://www.google.com/cloudprint/search?output=json to https://www.google.com/cloudprint/search

Check : https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/appInterfaces#search

/search  only supports the following parameters:
q, type, connection_status, use_cdd, extra_fields